# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4 Error

Tags: android

I'm trying to run my project and when I go to send a message I get this error:

> 

```
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.clarkawilson.quarkposts, PID: 22976
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clarkawilson.quarkposts.fragments.NotesFragment.updateMessageList(NotesFragment.java:177)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clarkawilson.quarkposts.handler.PostHandler.processRequestResult(PostHandler.java:261)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clarkawilson.quarkposts.handler.PostHandler.access$000(PostHandler.java:35)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clarkawilson.quarkposts.handler.PostHandler$1.onResponse(PostHandler.java:205)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.clarkawilson.quarkposts.handler.PostHandler$1.onResponse(PostHandler.java:202)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
09-28 20:33:40.591 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
09-28 20:33:42.161 22976-22976/com.clarkawilson.quarkposts I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22976 SIG: 9
```

NoteFragment:

```
public void updateMessageList(JSONObject jsonObject){
    try {

        /* The elements of incomingNotes are added into the noteList in reverse order,
         * i.e. treat incoming notes like a stack, so that the message we view at the
         * bottom of our adapter, is the last message received by the server.
         *
         * The second evaluation in the if statement tests whether the last element in
         * noteList is the same at the first element in the incoming list from the server.
         * If they're different, this means that new messages have been posted on the server.
         * If they're the same, nothing has changed. Don't traverse incomingList.*/

        JSONArray incomingNotes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(PostHandler.TAG_POSTS);
        NoteData nd = new NoteData(incomingNotes.getJSONObject(0));

        int incomingNotesLength = incomingNotes.length();
        if (null == noteList || !nd.equals(noteList.get(incomingNotesLength - 1))) {
            noteList = new ArrayList<>(incomingNotesLength);

            for (int i = incomingNotesLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                JSONObject c = incomingNotes.getJSONObject(i);
                NoteData noteData = new NoteData(c);
                noteList.add(noteData);
            }
            updateMessageList();
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(activity,
                ERROR_GENERAL + ": " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

PostHandler:

```
public class PostHandler {

public static final String SERVER_DIRECTORY = "http://-------/";
public static final String IMAGES_DIRECTORY = "uploadedimages/";
public static final String DEFAULT_AVATAR = "ic_action_camera";
public static final String READ_NOTES_URL = SERVER_DIRECTORY + "notes.php";
public static final String POST_NOTES_URL = SERVER_DIRECTORY + "addnote.php";
public static final String LOGIN_URL = SERVER_DIRECTORY + "login.php";
public static final String REGISTER_URL = SERVER_DIRECTORY + "register.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_IMAGE = SERVER_DIRECTORY + "upload_image.php";
public static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = ".PNG";
public static final String LOGIN_USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR ="Username/password combination not registered.";
public static final String REGISTER_SUCCESS = "Successfully registered";
public static final String REGISTER_USERNAME_ERROR = "Username taken, try a different one!";
private static final String SERVER_ERROR = "Unexpected error from server, try updating app.";

public static String getDefaultAvatarUrl(){
    return SERVER_DIRECTORY + IMAGES_DIRECTORY + DEFAULT_AVATAR + IMAGE_TYPE;
}

/* Converts the avatar image into a String to be posted with the JSON request */
public static String encodeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
}

/* Singleton instance, getter, and private constructor */
private static PostHandler singletonInstance;
public static PostHandler getSingletonInstanceSetSuperFragment(SuperFragment superFragment) {
    if (null == singletonInstance)
        singletonInstance = new PostHandler();

    singletonInstance.setSuperFragment(superFragment);
    return singletonInstance;
}

private PostHandler(){}
private static AppController appController = AppController.getInstance();
private static ImageLoader imageLoader = appController.getImageLoader();
private SuperFragment superFragment;
private NotesFragment notesFragment;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String username, password;
private Bitmap avatarBitmap;


/* Private so user can only work with one fragment at a time, thus not allowed to
 * have any other combination of superFragment and notesFragment other than the following:
 * superFragment == notesFragment OR notesFragment == null */
private void setSuperFragment(SuperFragment superFragment){
    if(pDialog != null) pDialog.dismiss();

    this.superFragment = superFragment;
    if(superFragment instanceof NotesFragment)
        this.notesFragment = (NotesFragment)superFragment;
    else
        this.notesFragment = null;
}

/* Sets the PostHandler's bitmap, but does not upload it. */
public void setAvatarBitmap(Bitmap b){
    avatarBitmap = b;
    if(hasNotesFragment()) postAvatar(b);
}


/* If username not yet submitted, return default avatar url. */
public String getUsernameAvatarUrl(){
    return getUsernameAvatarUrl(username);
}

public static String getUsernameAvatarUrl(String username){
    if(null != username) return SERVER_DIRECTORY + IMAGES_DIRECTORY + username + IMAGE_TYPE;
    return getDefaultAvatarUrl();
}

private boolean hasNotesFragment(){return null != notesFragment;}
public boolean hasUsername(){return null != username && !username.isEmpty();}
public String getUsername() {return username;}
public static AppController getAppController() {return appController;}
public static ImageLoader getImageLoader() {return imageLoader;}
public static void clearImageCache(){appController.clearCache();}

/* Username and password are only modifiable externally by these public post methods
 * to maintain consistent login information across all fragments using the handler. */
public void postLogin(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    postLogin();
}

public void postMessage(String username, String message){
    this.username = username;
    postMessage(message);
}

public void postRegister(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    postRegister();
}

public void updateNotesFragmentMessages(){
    if(hasNotesFragment())
        attemptGet(READ_NOTES_URL, false);
}

private void postAvatar(Bitmap b){
    String encodedString = encodeBitmap(b);
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("image", encodedString);
    attemptPost(UPLOAD_IMAGE, params, false);
}

private void postLogin(){
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    attemptPost(LOGIN_URL, params, true);
}
private void postMessage(String message){
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("message", message);
    attemptPost(POST_NOTES_URL, params, false);
}

private void postRegister(){
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    attemptPost(REGISTER_URL, params, true);
}


/* Creates a dialog to indicate that work is being done.*/
private void createProgressDialog(){
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(superFragment.getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Working...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}


private void attemptGet(String url, boolean useProgressDialog){
    attemptHTTP(Request.Method.GET, url, new HashMap<String, String>(), useProgressDialog);
}

private void attemptPost(String url, HashMap<String,String> params, boolean useProgressDialog){
    attemptHTTP(Request.Method.POST, url, params, useProgressDialog);
}

 /* Sends a post/get request using the Google Volley library's queue. */
private void attemptHTTP(int method, String url,
                         final HashMap<String,String> params,
                         boolean useProgressDialog){
    if(useProgressDialog) {
        createProgressDialog();
    }

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(method, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    processRequestResult(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {return params;}
            };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
}

/* Decide what to do after server responds to attemptHTTP call. Server replies with an int
* response encoded by its .php files; here we decode this response. */
private void processRequestResult(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        int result = jsonResponse.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        pDialog.dismiss();

        switch (result) {
            case 0: // username password combination error
                Toast.makeText(superFragment.getActivity(),
                        LOGIN_USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 1: // login successful
                if (null != avatarBitmap) postAvatar(avatarBitmap);
                else superFragment.loadNotesFragment();
                break;

            case 2: // registration success
                Toast.makeText(superFragment.getActivity(),
                        REGISTER_SUCCESS, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                postAvatar(avatarBitmap);
                break;

            case 3: // username already registered
                Toast.makeText(superFragment.getActivity(),
                        REGISTER_USERNAME_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 4: // avatar successfully uploaded
                if(hasNotesFragment()) notesFragment.updateMessageListAvatars();
                else superFragment.loadNotesFragment();
                break;

            case 5: // message successfully posted
                if(hasNotesFragment()) updateNotesFragmentMessages();
                break;

            case 6: // messages list successfully returned
                if(hasNotesFragment()) {notesFragment.updateMessageList(jsonResponse);}
                break;

            default: break;
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(superFragment.getActivity(), SERVER_ERROR, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Any help with this would be grateful.
I'm sure I've probably missed a bit of code even though I checked it 3 or 4 times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve the 5th item in a list that only has 4 items in it.  The trouble is coming from this line of code

```
if (null == noteList || !nd.equals(noteList.get(incomingNotesLength - 1))) {
```

Particularly `noteList.get(incomingNotesLength - 1))`

This is failing because `incomingNotesLength` is initialized to `incomingNotes.length();`, not `noteList.size()`.

If you are trying to retrieve the last item in `noteList`, you should change this line of code to

```
if (null == noteList || !nd.equals(noteList.get(noteList.size() - 1))) {
```

or

```
int noteListLength = noteList.size();
if (null == noteList || !nd.equals(noteList.get(noteListLength - 1))) {
```

Comment: Okay so am I changing the code to:

`if (null == noteList || !nd.equals(noteList.get(noteList.length() - 1))) {
                noteList = new ArrayList<>(incomingNotesLength);`

Comment: There are many ways you can fix this trivial issue; how you choose to do that is up to you.  Do you understand the problem with your original code?

Comment: I kinda understand but it doesn't recognise .length in noteList.length()

Comment: My mistake, that should be `.size()`

Comment: `if (null == noteList || !nd.equals(noteList.get(noteList.size() - 1))) {` This line of code has worked perfectly!! Thank you!